# Two SCHEMA of the same DATABASE MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, schema, mysql-workbench

I am relatively new to MySQL and I'm lovin' it.
What I'm trying to do is to have two different SCHEMAS on the same database.  --Actually I'm getting confused with the terminology in this case-- So allow me to paint you the whole picture.

I have a database (say financial) on which I'm running a (risk mathematical) model.  So I load the database in my computer and manipulate it with another program.
In order to test the model I need to load a previous backup -say last month's- of said database and run the model as if I was living in the past, and then test it with this month's data.

From what I understood, this backup replaced the database that I was already using.  And this is not optimal to me, since then I have to reload the current version of the same database.  Ideally I would like to have both of them stored in my computer and switch from one to the other, instead of reloading each every time.

If anyone can give me some guidance, I'll appreciate it. 
Have a good day.

Comment: [`RENAME DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html). Just have "live" and "devel" and rename between them. Your app always uses the same name, you just change which database that actually happens to be by renaming as appropriate.

Comment: You may want to look at point-in-time architecture - but that stuff's beyond my pay-grade.

Comment: @MarcB At what level can I -and should I- differentiate them (schema, database)?  I created two connections in my client (Workbench), but then noticed that loading one backup in one connection, modifies the data in the other.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for your suggestion.  Being relatively new with this program, looking into the architecture of the database seems beyond my pay-grade as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: `database` and `schema` are the same. Both are interchangable (in MySQL). A schema is the top level structure in your database server containing all the other db objects that belong to it. There's also the notion of catalogs in MySQL (as real top level structures), but they are never used so far.

When creating 2 connections to the same server (you are creating connections to a server, not a database) you will access the same objects and hence the same data, regardless which connection you choose (subject to the privileges of the users used for the connections). So, that is of no help in your case.

You can have as many schemas as you like, e.g., as has been suggested, a development schema and a prodcution schema. They can both be stored in the same database server and can contain exactly the same content. With your dump you can create another schema for testing. MySQL Workbench allows to restore it into a different schema than what is specfied in the dump file.

[image]

Now, in order to switch between the current and the old data you have 2 options:

1. Rename you schemas so that the one you want to work with at the moment has the standard name as used in your application.
2. Make your application configurable to accept a database/schema name via settings, command line params etc.

The second is clearly more flexible, especially if you start having more historical data (in even more schemas).